# Convert a vertical menu to horizontal in CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

I am using a menu and I am trying to change the way it looks. I want the submenus (ul li) to be horizontal and not vertical. I tried everything on CSS like adding `float` but nothing worked.

I am using this HTML code :

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Page2</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Page1</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Page3</a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'>Page4</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>About</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>YOLO</a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am using this CSS code :

```css
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 23px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #9e3825;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(116, 37, 2, 0.7);
  line-height: 18px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  line-height: 18px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active {
  background: url(images/active.png) repeat;
}
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 64px;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a {
  padding: 18px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: #393939;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 150px;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid #de553b;
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:active {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat;
}
```

Comment: display:inline-block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?

```css
body{
  background: #CCC;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#cssmenu:before,
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:before,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 23px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #9e3825;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(116, 37, 2, 0.7);
  line-height: 18px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #97321f;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(122, 42, 26, 0.64);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  line-height: 18px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:active {
  background: url(images/active.png) repeat;
}
/* Childs */
#cssmenu > ul ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  background: url(images/highlight-bg.png) repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a {
  padding: 18px 26px;
  display: block;
  color: #393939;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:hover {
  border-left: 4px solid #de553b;
  background: url(images/hover.png) repeat;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a:active {
  background: url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat;
}
```

```html
 <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Page2</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Page1</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Page3</a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'>Page4</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>About</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>YOLO</a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```